# java web service proxy client

Tags: java, web-services, http, proxy, http-proxy

I am working on a bank network which  is a closed network. We have deployed web service client(create using apache cxf). The bank uses proxy to connect to outside network.
So how would i tell the web service java client to use the network proxy which bank has set.
Thanks in advance. A more clear solution would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

configure the proxy server on the HTTPClientPolicy object and set it on the HttpConduit object retrieved from proxy object or client.

```
HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
policy.setProxyServer("<<proxyServer>>");
policy.setProxyServerPort("<<proxyPort>>");
httpConduit.setClient(policy);
```